# why preview image is blank for ImageMosaicJDBC (postgis raster) layer?

Tags: postgis, raster, geoserver, mosaic

I follow http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/pgraster.html to publish a ImageMosaicJDBC layer in geoserver.
the layer seems published ok and saved, but the preview of this layer does not give me a meaningful overview image, only a blank image with the correct lat lon extent.  Also I don’t know why I got two bands when I get feature info, the geotiff that goes into postgis raster table only has one band.  In the contrast, using Quantum GIS Lisboa I can see greyscale image after adding layer for the Postgis raster table in postgres.

below is what I have done:

step 1: Translate netCDF into GeoTiff: 
`$ gdal_translate.exe -of GTiff -scale -32766 32766 -32766 32766 -ot INT16 gebco_08_-12_-51_11_54.nc gebco08part2.tif`

step 2: Load GeoTiff into Postgres as PostGIS raster table:
`C:\temp>"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\raster2pgsql.exe" -s 4326 -I -C -M gebco08part2.tif | "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\psql.exe" -d postgis20 -U postgres`

step 3: Create master table and tile table in Postgres:
`create table gebco_master2 (NAME varchar(254) not null,
         TileTable varchar(254)not null,
         minX FLOAT8,minY FLOAT8, maxX FLOAT8, maxY FLOAT8,resX FLOAT8, resY FLOAT8,
         primary key (NAME,TileTable))`

`insert into gebco_master2(NAME,TileTable) values ('gebco_cover','gebco08part2')`

step 4: Configure mosaic JDBC plugin in geoserver:
gebco.pgraster.xml: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ImageMosaicJDBCConfig [
      <!ENTITY mapping PUBLIC "mapping"  "mapping.pgraster.xml.inc">
      <!ENTITY connect PUBLIC "connect"  "connect.pgraster.xml.inc">
]>
<config version="1.0">
      <coverageName name="gebco_cover"/>
      <coordsys name="EPSG:4326"/>
      <scaleop  interpolation="1"/>
      &mapping;
      &connect;
</config>`

connect.pgraster.xml.inc:
`<connect>
  <!-- value DBCP or JNDI -->
  <dstype value="DBCP"/>
  <!--   <jndiReferenceName value=""/>  -->
  <username value="postgres" />
  <password value="password" />
  <jdbcUrl value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgis20" />
  <driverClassName value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <maxActive value="10"/>
  <maxIdle value="0"/>
</connect>`

mapping.pgraster.xml.inc:
`<spatialExtension name="pgraster"/>
 <mapping>
      <masterTable name="gebco_master2" >
              <coverageNameAttribute name="name"/>
              <maxXAttribute name="maxx"/>
              <maxYAttribute name="maxy"/>
              <minXAttribute name="minx"/>
              <minYAttribute name="miny"/>
              <resXAttribute name="resx"/>
              <resYAttribute name="resy"/>
              <tileTableNameAtribute name="tiletable" />
      </masterTable>
      <tileTable>
              <blobAttributeName name="rast" />
              <keyAttributeName name="rid" />
      </tileTable>
</mapping>`

step 5: Then add ImageMosaicJDBC store and layer in geoserver:
URL Connection Parameters:
file:coverages/gebco.pgraster.xml

I believe the postgis raster table in postgres database should be correct otherwise quantum gis won't be able to view it, the question is have I configured geoserver correctly, why the preview image is blank?

Comment: What Bit is the image from postgres in? (8bit 24 bit?) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth

Comment: I gdal_translate the netCDF gebco data into 16 bit (because gebco data is 16 bit format) GTiff file before importing into the postgis20 database, so it should be 16 bit images in postgres

Comment: I used BYTE instead of INT16 during gdal_translate, now I can preview the gebco data. seems geoserver can only handle 8bits or 24bits? thanks Mapperz for the hints